# How to train wiki with Doc2Vec Wiki with case insensitive features

Tags: python-3.x, mediawiki, gensim, doc2vec

I am following this blog trying to train doc2vec on wikipedia corpus using gensim. https://markroxor.github.io/gensim/static/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.html.

I notice that the output is extremely case-sensitive. For example,

```
string1=model.infer_vector("machine Learning".split())
string2=model.infer_vector("computer Science".split())
spatial.distance.cosine(string1, string2)
output is 0.25
```

If I change the case for the input,

```
string1=model.infer_vector("machine learning".split())
string2=model.infer_vector("computer science".split())
spatial.distance.cosine(string1, string2)
output is 1.0535
```

I think that I should lower case everything before train the model. However, as shown in the link above, I first read the input directly:

```
class TaggedWikiDocument(object):
    def __init__(self, wiki):
        self.wiki = wiki
        self.wiki.metadata = True
    def __iter__(self):
        for content, (page_id, title) in self.wiki.get_texts():
            yield TaggedDocument([c for c in content], [title])
wiki = WikiCorpus("enwiki-latest-pages-articles-sample2.xml.bz2")
documents = TaggedWikiDocument(wiki)
```

Any suggestion on how I can lower all the cases in the wiki document?

By the way, I used a very small file size for now just to test out whether there are errors in running the code, hence it can be the reason that infer_vector is very sensitive to case. Maybe this problem is minimum if I use the actual wiki dataset ?

Comment: Your code currently doesn't show any case-variation in your two tests – they appear identical, and already all-lowercase. Also, `1.0535` is a very suspicious output value – cosine distance usually maxes at 1.0. Are you sure you're showing actual execution inputs/results in your example code?

Comment: Just edited so that one is with cap and the other with lower case. I am not sure why the distance is >1, but this is the actual output result